# How to add 1 more breakdown color in plotly funnel?

Tags: python-3.x, plotly, plotly-express

I have 1 state on "og"- false, and 2 states on "no og" true and false

| is_retargeting | media_source | step | Values |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| False | og | step1 | 31992 |
| True | no og | step1 | 33644 |
| False | no og | step1 | 32199 |
| False | no og | step2 | 20699 |
| False | og | step2 | 47796 |
| True | no og | step2 | 23668 |
| True | no og | step3 | 10744 |
| False | no og | step3 | 27622 |
| False | og | step3 | 20979 |
| False | no og | step4 | 16459 |
| False | og | step4 | 28444 |
| True | no og | step4 | 49749 |

i come up with this code, but it shows only 2 colors but breaks "no og" with no explanation.
here is the screenshot what i get
[image]

How can add one more breakdown column `is_retargeting` for this funnel so it will show true or false for "no og"?

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('max_columns', None)
df = pd.read_csv("name.csv")

df.loc[df["media_source"] != "organic", "media_source"] = 'non organic'
df = df.groupby(['is_retargeting', 'media_source']).sum().reset_index()
df1 = df.melt(id_vars=["is_retargeting", "media_source"],
        var_name="step",
        value_name="Values")
fig = px.funnel(df1, x='Values', y='step', color='media_source')
fig.show()
```